# Two similar animations behave differently

Tags: ios, animation, view, coordinates

I have a UIView configured through Storyboard. This view (`self.view`) has one child, a button (`self.cartButton`). Later in the code I add a `subview` to this `view`:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.cart.view];
```

I have the following method:

```
- (void)openCart
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        self.cartButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.cartButton.frame.size.width, self.cartButton.frame.size.height);
        self.cart.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.cart.view.frame.size.width, self.cart.view.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

I think it should move both objects to the top of the screen, but what really happens is that the cartButton animates to the bottom most position, and the cart view to the top. Why does this happen? Did I mess up the coordinate systems somewhere?

UPDATE: If I comment out the second line in the animation (animating the cart view), `cartButton` flies to the top.

UPDATE2: It has something to do with my `cartView`. It is a generic view (created in Storyboard). When I try to do the same animation for example with a `NavigationController`, it works.

UPDATE3: If my cart view has no subviews, it works fine. If it has anything in it (a button, `navigationBar`, anything...), it does not work.

Comment: How is the button added in the view ?

Comment: With the Interface Designer.

Comment: Do you have auto layout enabled?

Comment: Yes, I do. The button looks like this:

[Image](http://gk.lka.hu/x/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-13%20at%2011.45.25.png)